# secure connection conflict between HTTPS and HTTP protocols on different hosting platforms

Tags: http, https

I am facing a secure connection conflict as some of my videos are hosted on Kaltura (http) while the site is hosted on Heroku (HTTPS). Can you guys/girls advise on how to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a proxy in your Heroku backend. The steps would be:

1. The video request is sent through HTTPS protocol to the proxy.
2. The proxy receive the request, parse it, and fetch corresponding video through HTTP from Kaltura.
3. The proxy return video data to browser.