# http iframe content on https site

Tags: asp.net, http, cross-browser

asp.net 4.5.2, html5 etc

Our site is on https.  However, we need to embed an iframe which calls out to a service that is not available over https.

Chrome blocks this so the embedded content does not display.

Is there any way in asp.net config to reliably force this content to be displayed in spite of it only being available over http?

Comment: You can make a proxy in your backend code, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171882/secure-connection-conflict-between-https-and-http-protocols-on-different-hosting/43226478#43226478

Comment: I'm not sure how any of this could be achieved as that article does not explain enough

Comment: Basically, a `proxy` means you create your own backend route (https), accept request from browser and pipe that request to `service that is not available over https`. This can be done because unlike browser, there is no http-in-https security limit in backend.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still none the wiser.  I wish to know 'how' to do this so need help from somebody who can go into detail

Comment: Can you go into more detail for asp.net / iis etc?

Comment: Sorry @wingyip but I'm not familiar with asp.net and iis, thus unable to provide detail examples. However, this is a common practice and can be implemented in all backend technologies.